# Vertical align button in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I'm doing a website using the **Twitter-Boostrap** framework and I would like to put a `navbar-toggle button` at the far right side of the navigation bar, aligned **exactly** in the middle.

How can I do this?

Here is what I did:

[image: current state]

```css
.navbar-default .container {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #2E8B57;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1.5px #FFFFFF;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!--Container-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="index.html">Food, LLC</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--END Navbar-header -->


    <!-- Toggle Button -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `top: 13px;` use `top: 50%` with `transform: translateY(-50%)`, see the following snippet:

```css
.navbar-default .container {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #2E8B57;
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1.5px #FFFFFF;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!--Container-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="index.html">Food, LLC</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--END Navbar-header -->


    <!-- Toggle Button -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, Kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references :)